# How to use custom_dimension in Google Analytics API with gaapi4py library?

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using a gaapi4py library to connect to Google Analytics API and it works fine unless I need to put a user_id in dimension list. My request body is following:

```
request_body = {
    'view_id': '123456789',
    'start_date': '2022-09-11',
    'end_date': '2022-09-14',
    'dimensions': {
        'ga:date',
        'ga:Browser',
        'ga:city',
        'ga:ga_user_id'
    },
    'metrics': {
        'ga:sessions'
    }
```

This code does not work since last dimension is a custom one and I get an error:
"Unknown dimension(s): ga:ga_user_id". Is there any way to handle with custom dimensions in gaapi4py?

Comment: I recomend having a look at the [dimensions and metrics exploerer](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/dimensions-metrics-explorer/)  there is no dimension called ga_user_id you can only use valid dimensions.

Comment: Yes, there are no such dimension, because it is a custom dimension and my question is how to work with custom dimension in this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an issue with the library this is how the api works.   customer dimensions use ga:dimensionXX where XX is the number of the Custom dimension configured in your system

Comment: If the answer helped remember to accept it it will also improve your reputation.